# A higher level (do-what-i-mean) alternative to jq for filtering json?

Tags: command-line, json

I'm looking for a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but which is easier to use for normal use cases (but less powerful), before I write one myself.

**Context**

I often find myself interacting with *json* stream, it is very natural for a program to produce a stream of JSON which other programs can filter.

`jq` is wonderful for complicated queries, and I know it well enough to write most of the queries I use without reference to documentation. However, for simpler things the amount of boiler plate can be a little excessive. For example look at

```
program | jq 'select(.field | test("match", i))'
```

and compare it to

```
program | grep -i match
```

**Desired tool**

Is there any tool which is more of a middle ground: less power but less boiler-plate.

Maybe something like:

```
program | json-filter --field match --filter key1,key2,key3
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx)

It's plain JavaScript cli JSON manipulating tool (alternative to jq) with standalone binary.

```
program | fx 'input => input.filter(x => ...).map(x => {a: a.x})'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) (github, >8700 stars) might help to *make JSON greppable* .

Then the pipeline is `< my.json gron | grep -v "something-to-remove" | gron -u`

The readme has much better examples.